# Plotly Scatterpolar change fill, line and hover color

Tags: python, charts, plotly, scatter-plot, plotly-python

I have the following example. I can change the fill color to 'green' following the [documentation](https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Scatterpolar.html?highlight=scatterpolar#plotly.graph_objects.Scatterpolar) but I cannot find how to change the line/dots and tooltip colours to the same one. What's the best way to change all into one colour?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.wind()
df_test = df[df["strength"]=='0-1']
fig.data=[]
fig.add_trace(go.Scatterpolar(r=df_test['frequency'], theta=df_test['direction'],fill='toself',fillcolor='green'))

fig.show(config= {'displaylogo': False})
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the same color to the line so that the hover color will also be the same. I then disabled the grid on the graph to match the image presented.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = px.data.wind()
df_test = df[df["strength"]=='0-1']

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatterpolar(r=df_test['frequency'],
                              theta=df_test['direction'],
                              fill='toself',
                              fillcolor='green',
                              line_color='green',
                             ))

fig.update_layout(polar=dict(radialaxis=dict(visible=False)))

fig.show(config= {'displaylogo': False})
```

[image]